# I have no idea why only one code has SIGSEGV between two code (looks same)

Tags: c++

First time, I coded like this (I was making a trie) and when I called add("911"); I got a segmentation fault at there when *str == '1'

```
struct Node {
    int check, check2;
    Node* chd[10];
    Node() : check(0), check2(0), chd{0, } {}
    ~Node() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            if (chd[i])
                delete chd[i];
    }
    int add(char* str) {
        if (!str[0])
            return 0;
        if (chd[*str-'0'] == 0)          // here I got SIGSEGV
            chd[*str-'0'] = new Node();
        ...
        return chd[*str-'0']->add(++str);
    }
}
```

then I fixed that part like this

```
        int i = *str-'0';
        if (chd[i] == 0)
            chd[i] = new Node();
```

**there was no error.**

**What's the difference? What made the first code make error?**

(I was solving ACM-ICPC > Regionals > Europe > Northwestern European Regional Contest > Nordic Collegiate Programming Contest > NCPC 2007 A)

Comment: please show a [mvce], weird changes in behaviour in one place are often caused by undefined behaviour elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And note that the cause of the problem might not be where the crash actually happens. And besides a [mcve], can you please include the call-stack when the crash happens, as well as the values of involved variables (most importantly what is `*str`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return chd[*str-'0']->add(++str);`

contains undefined behavoir as you are modifying and using `str` unsequenced.

Your 'fix' has the classic behavoir of moving something around enough that the undefined behavoir is hidden. Remeber that *Undefined Behavoir* is undefined. It doens't have to crash. It doesn't even have to make sense. And most scarily it can do what you expect... for the time being at least.

A simple change is:

`return chd[*str-'0']->add(str+1);`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This line has undefined behaviour

```
return chd[*str-'0']->add(++str);
```

because the modification and the use of `str` are unsequenced.

The quick fix is (don't say `++` when you mean `+ 1`):

```
return chd[*str-'0']->add(str + 1);
```

but you can also avoid the problem by computing the relevant index just once (it sounds like this is how you fixed the problem, and it's the better solution):

```
int add(char* str) {
    if (!str[0])
        return 0;
    char c = str[0] - '0';
    if (chd[c] == 0)
        chd[c] = new Node();
    ...
    return chd[c]->add(str + 1); // And ++str would also work...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!